# asp mvc repository patten dealing with complex queries and viewModels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

Before implementing UOW and Repository pattern i used to create conditional queries and return search results from my service layer:

For example:

`

```
private IQueryable<IssueSearchResult> GetIssuesQuery() {
        var query = (from iss in Dbcontext.Issues
                     join pr in Dbcontext.PurchaseRequisitions on iss.PrId equals pr.PrId
                     where iss.IssueDate>=SearchCriteria.FromDate && iss.IssueDate<=SearchCriteria.ToDate
                     select new IssueSearchResult()
                     {
                         IssueId = iss.IssueId,
                         IssueNo = iss.IssueNumber,
                         IssueDate = iss.IssueDate,
                         PrNo = pr.DocumentNumber,
                             CreatedByName = iss.User.FullName
                         });
// if(condition){
// query = query.where(etc);
//}

    return query.OrderBy(x => x.IssueId);
}
public async Task<List<IssueSearchResult>> GetAsyncIssues() {
    List<IssueSearchResult> issues = new List<IssueSearchResult>();
    try {
        issues = await GetIssuesQuery().ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (DataException) {
        throw;
    }
    return issues;
}
```

Now i am failling to figure out how to do the same using UOW and repository pattern as i cannot directly query entities and it is bad practice to return iqueryable from the repository.

I ve checked numerous SO post and cannot seem to find the solution.

Does it mean i should abandon Repository pattern altogether?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository will contain entity framework context property, so you will use it for querying. And repository method will return you list or single object. just like i show in this small example.

```
 public UnitofWork : IDisposable 
{
    private DBData Context;//context you can recieve from injection or from static method 
    public IssueRepository Issues => here goes method to check that you have only one repository of this type with this context
}

public class IssueRepository{
   constructor that takes dbContext

   public async Task<List<IssueSearchResult>> GetAsyncIssues() 
{
     List<IssueSearchResult> issues = new List<IssueSearchResult>();
try {
    issues = await context.Issues.Where(expression).Select(x => new IssueSearchResult()
                 {
                     IssueId = iss.IssueId,
                     IssueNo = iss.IssueNumber,
                     IssueDate = iss.IssueDate,
                     PrNo = pr.DocumentNumber,
                         CreatedByName = iss.User.FullName
                     }).ToListAsync();
}
catch (DataException) {
    throw;
}
return issues;
}
}
```

Also you can use projection classes and Automapper or some other library to map results into viewmodel and back.

Comment: So My Repository will return a viewmodel

Comment: `List<IssueSearchResult>` will be returned from IssueRepository. But from what i understand, repositories are not supposed to return viewmodels, correct me if i am wrong here

Comment: This is  link i was referring to in the above comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/344336/mvc-problems-with-passing-viewmodel-directly-to-from-repository

Comment: Repository returns domain model(entity) or projections. Then you have to map them into viewmodel with Automapper. Link that you found explains this very good.
IssueSearchResult can be projection and you can map it to IssueSearchResultViewModel class, that will have some service attributes or simple logic.

Comment: i think i got the terminology wrong between domain model and viewmodel

Comment: Yes, domain model and viewmodel is not the same. Separate them is good practice. Also if you want to understand UnitOfWork and Repository patterns you can read about Dependency Injection.